# hostname command returns nothing on ipv6 host

Tags: linux, ipv6

I have an RHEL host that is dual stacked for ipv4 and ipv6. Ipv6 is the primary, including all DNS records for the host. Ipv4 is a fall back to reach ipv4 only networks,  its even behind an ipv4 NAT.

ping6 gandalf works including the domain from resolv.conf.

hostname returns gandalf

hostname -f or hostname -a both return nothing. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I was able to reproduce this in a RHEL6 VM;

So, basically, there's a [known issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=648725) with regards to IPv6 & the hostname command. I'm not sure if this bug is exactly the issue you are experiencing, but I was able to get my VM to work properly.

Configuration for an IPv6-only host, though this shouldn't affect the IPv4 hostname resolution if you add it to both lines. You may need to experiment with your environment to find the magic config needed.
[image: Output of ip addr]

Before with a base install:
[image: Base Install]

After with a slight change to the /etc/hosts as per that bug.
[image: After a slight edit to the /etc/hosts]

Comment: Sorry, that's not it. /etc/hosts does not contain any references to the hostname or any address other than loopback.

Comment: Right, that's the crux of the bug that I linked to. If you put the local hostname on the IPv6 line, the 'hostname' command should start resolving properly for the IPv6 interface. This is obviously not an ideal situation -- but it may be a sufficient workaround for your use case.